# Not receiving emails from ExceptionNotifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason I'm not getting any emails from ExceptionNotifier. I followed the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818532/766953.

I did this test:

```
so@plike:~/proj$ bundle exec rake middleware | grep ExceptionNotifier
so@plike:~/proj$ use ExceptionNotifier
```

And see this in the server logs:

```
Sent mail to stackOverlord@yahoo.com (53ms)
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2012 18:48:57 -0800
...
```

I've never sent email from my rails app before, is there any anything I'm missing? Also how does it magically send from whatever email address I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm had to add this to my environments/development.rb and enviroments/production.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'stackoverlord.com',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => 'mygmailusername@gmail.com',
    :password => 'mygmailpassword'
  }
end
```